# How do I use a target's path in add_custom_command in CMake?

Tags: cmake

In CMakeLists.txt have a library called "library.dll". I want to add a post build event to copy the resulting file to a different directory. The documentation says to use generator events, but it's not working:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET library.dll POST_BUILD COMMAND copy $<TARGET_FILE:library.dll> \"${SOME_DIR}/bin\")
```

I'm using CMake 2.8.3 to generate VC++ 2010 project files on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following changes:

Add the VERBATIM option which ensures that all arguments to the command will be escaped properly.

Instead of using the Windows built-in copy command, invoke CMake in command mode which has a platform independent copy command built-in.

The modified command looks like this:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET library.dll POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_FILE:library.dll> ${SOME_DIR}/bin VERBATIM)
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! The only problem was that you can't have a '.' in the target name, which is fixed as of 2.8.4: http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=12002.

Comment: The bug http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=12002 was reported in CMake 2.8.4 -- it was just reported and fixed only 2 days ago. The fix will not appear until the *next* release of CMake. The "generator expression" feature used in the original question ( $<TARGET_FILE: ... ) is new for add_custom_command in CMake 2.8.4. It will not work as you expect in CMake 2.8.3, because it is not implemented in that version.

Comment: CMake 2.8.5 has been released, so this should no longer be an issue.